# Laplace Transform piecewise function with domain from 1 to inf

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have been asked to compute the Laplace Transform of the following piecewise function

\begin{equation}
f(t) = \begin{cases}
t - 1 \quad 1 \leq t < 2 \\
3 - t \quad 2 \leq t < 3 \\
0 \quad t \geq 3
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

I could not find an example where the domain of the piecewise function to transform does not begin at $0$, I was wondering if it could be possible to shift the function to the left $f(t + 1)$, so that the domain begins at $0$, rewrite in terms of the unit step function and transform it. Is that something valid to do? or how should these cases be handled?

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you can't Laplace transform a function which is not defined from $0$ to $1$ as well. I assume you are expected to take $f(t)=0$ for $t<1$.

Comment: @kevinkayaks I'm not given more information other than computing the Laplace Transform. I tried calculating it using the definition, but as you mention, I must know what happens between 0 and 1. It is a homework assignment and I presume it may be my teacher's mistake, because otherwise it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Office hours. You can't integrate a function where it isn't defined. This has no meaning. If the function is $f(t)=0$ for $t<1$ you have $\tilde{f}(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st}f(t)dt = \int_1^2 e^{-st}(t-1) dt + \int_2^3 e^{-st} (3-t)dt$ which you can evaluate easily.

Answer (score 1):

Set $b(t)=u(t)-u(t-1)$ as the unit box or square function with support $[0,1]$. Then your function can be represented as
$$
f(t)=(b*b)(t-1),
$$
check it that the convolution of $b$ with itself gives the hat function. Now apply standard Laplace rules
$$
\begin{align}
{\cal L}\{f(t)\}(s)&=e^{-s}{\cal L}\{(b*b)(t)\}\\
&=e^{-s}\Bigl({\cal L}\{b(t)\}\Bigr)^2
\end{align}
$$
etc.